# Spring-Boot starter test import not resolved

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, ubuntu-16.04, spring-boot-test

```
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
```

Test package can't be resolved
Spring Boot version 2.0.3
Gradle version 4.6
JDK 1.8

I am using IntelliJ community edition IDE and my OS is ubuntu-16.04

Tried also to:
1-import springframework.boot.test but this also does not work
2- navigate to the project directory and building the project using the terminal

I prefer not to import the libraries manually.

Gradle Script:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Statement : `testCompile("junit:junit")` , not needed

dependency:

```
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

Resolving following class:

```
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
```

Comment: testCompile("junit:junit") I need because I import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

Comment: also, I already have this dependency included and it is still not working

Comment: Is there any error in build window at the bottom of intelliJ?

Comment: No, and i tried building using the terminal also both builds successfully

Comment: Use Alt+Enter and check suggestions and click on add in suggestion window. 
Same dependencies are working for me:
dependencies {
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
 testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}